# Get video object (or video id) from Facebook timeline post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, html5-video

I'm trying to get a Facebook [video](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video) object from a timeline post :

1. I'm getting the posts from graph api /me/home
2. I can easily get the photo object via the returned object_id
3. The problem is there is no object_id value for video post type

   ```
   {
      "id": "750834774_10152138100019775", 
      "from": {
         "id": "750834774", 
         "name": "Emilie Volpi"
      }, 
      "message": "haha le monde qui fait une analyse geopolitique de games of thrones^^ une bonne manière de se remettre à jour pour la nouvelle saison demain !!!!!", 
      "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCclQTe2bPMIcrY&w=130&h=130&url=http%3A%2F%2Fs2.dmcdn.net%2FEHFV4%2F526x297-mO8.jpg", 
      "link": "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1lu3ke_game-of-thrones-comprendre-la-crise-a-westeros-en-4-minutes_news", 
      "source": "http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/video/x1lu3ke?autoPlay=1", 
      "name": "« Game of Thrones » : comprendre la crise à Westeros en 4 minutes", 
      "caption": "www.dailymotion.com", 
      "description": "Guerre des cinq rois, pression des marcheurs blancs et des sauvageons au nord, retour des dragons à l’est… le Royaume des Sept couronnes est plongée dans une crise politique sanglante depuis plus d’un an. Le Monde vous propose un décryptage de la crise en quatre minutes mais attention… spoilers !", 
      "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yj/r/v2OnaTyTQZE.gif", 
      "actions": [
         {
            "name": "Comment", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/750834774/posts/10152138100019775"
         }, 
         {
            "name": "Like", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/750834774/posts/10152138100019775"
         }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
         "value": ""
      },
      "type": "video", 
      "status_type": "shared_story", 
      "application": {
      "name": "Links", 
      "id": "2309869772"
    }, 
    "created_time": "2014-04-06T09:39:57+0000", 
    "updated_time": "2014-04-06T09:39:57+0000", 
    "likes": {
       "data": [
         {
           "id": "1283687218", 
           "name": "Max Imus"
         }
       ], 
       "paging": {
          "cursors": {
             "after": "MTI4MzY4NzIxOA==", 
             "before": "MTI4MzY4NzIxOA=="
          }
       }
     }
   },
   ```

As you can see there is no video id so I can't get the video

My goal is to retrieve the embed_html from the [video](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video) object

Please tell me how to do that (graph api or FQL query)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only get the embed_html for videos which are actually hosted on Facebook. The example you're using is hosted on dailymotion and only referenced in the post. That's the main difference.

I guess you could use the following FQL to get the embeddable video url:

```
select attachment.media.video.source_url from stream where post_id='750834774_10152138100019775'
```

You can then include it dynmically in your page if you pass the source_url content to an iFrame as src attribute for example

Comment: You might be right, I believed Facebook has had also the embed_html for all the shared video. I don't need to retrieve the source_url again since I already got it :) The problem is I try in an Android context and the WebView doesn't always read the source_url (flash ...)

Comment: Well, then I think it's not really possible what you are trying to achieve here...